# Passing C++ Lambda Functions

Tags: c++, lambda

I've been searching everywhere for this, and I don't seem to be able to find a straight answer. Some sources say this isn't possible, but that only raises more questions for me, which I'll explain further below.

So here's the situation. Suppose I have a custom container class with a selection function like below (this is just an example):

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
    // ...

    Container<T> select(bool (*condition)(const T&)) const;

    // ...
};
```

So as you can see, the `select` function takes a pointer to a **condition** function. This is a function that defines which items should be selected. So, an example use of this would be something similar to:

```
bool zero_selector(const int& element) {
    return (element == 0); // Selects all elements that are zero
}
```

Now if I have a container filled with, say `s = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }`, I could select a subset of these that would only contain zeroes using:

```
t = s.select(&zero_selector); // t = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

As you can see, this is a bit clunky. Lambda functions would make this much more elegant, so then I could use (I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax for it), for example:

```
t = s.select([&] (int x) -> bool { return (x == 0); });
```

My question is, is this possible? If so, what should my function prototype be for `Container::select()` to accept a lambda as one of its parameters?

If it isn't possible, then how is something like `std::for_each` implemented that can use a lambda expression as one of its arguments? Any resources that would clearly explain this would be much appreciated. Everything I've found just gives examples of lambda functions and using `std::function<>` to pass them as parameters, but nothing explains how `std::for_each` works with lambda functions.

I'd like to note that this code isn't compiled/tested as-is. It's for demonstration purposes only. I have tried implementing the same principles in the actual project and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to declare your lambda as stateless (that is, with an empty capture specification `[](int x)-> bool {...}`) for it to be convertable to a function pointer.

Comment: Or use `std::function`, or make `select` a template

Comment: I tried your solution (on the exact code posted above by removing the `&`), and it doesn't work. It gives me error C2664 because it can't convert '`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(const T &)'.

Comment: @teedayf, it's a newer addition to C++11. Visual Studio 2010 does not support it yet. And you would need to declare the lambda as `[](const int &x) {...}` to match the function pointer signature.

Comment: @MSN, Ah, I see. And yah, I tried the other prototype, and it didn't work either. So it's just not supported on VS2010 yet.

Comment: Should be in VS2011, though. They'll even deal with all the nasty STDCALL calling conventions, so you can pass stateless lambda's to e.g. `SetWindowsHookEx`

Answer (score 72):

There's no need to add the knee-jerk `[&]`-capture. Your lambda doesn't need it:

```
[] (int x) -> bool { return (x == 0); }
```

Captureless lambdas are convertible to the corresponding function pointer, so this should work out of the box.

That said, you should probably declare the select function to accept `std::function`, to which *all* lambdas are convertible, capturing or not:

```
Container<T> select(std::function<bool(const T&)> predicate) const;
```

Comment: What does `<bool(const T&)>` mean? A function taking one const argument of type T by reference and returning bool?

Comment: @Wilson: Yes, e.g. [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for compile time resolution (**template parameters**) over run-time resolution (`std::function`):

- No virtual function call.
  Normally I'd ignore the overhead but your example involves *iterating through a container*, which is the archetypical example of where we don't want unnecessary overhead!
- Your class is *already* a template, so there's not really anything to be lost by including another template parameter, if anything it's easier.
- May be inlined by the compiler.
- No unnecessary function-signature constraints.

So I'd use:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
    ...
    template<typename F>
    Container<T> select(F fun) const
    {
        ...
        foo = fun(bar)
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```